# Extra Alignment?

Tags: tables, errors

```
\documentclass[12pt, thesis]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{$-$}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{0cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,102,204}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont={color=blue,bf},up]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/} }
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt} % less gaps in itemize sections
\setenumerate{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{placeins}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace{20\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries
        % \@chapapp\space % removed
        \thechapter
        \nobreakspace{}% \par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@ % replaced
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge % \Huge % replaced
    \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 15\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{10pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{10pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{20pt}{3pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\small}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\small}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\setlength{\headheight}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\parskip}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.5\textfloatsep}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{10pt}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}{
    \begin{longtable}{M{2.5cm}M{7.20cm}M{7.25cm}M{7.5cm}} 
    \caption{Type of debridement techniques. \textit{Adapted from Gray et al. (2011), Vowden (2011).}}
    \label{techn}
    \hline \hline \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Mode of Action} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Surgical} & Removal of necrotic and healthy tissue to achieve a healthy bleeding wound & \tabitem Selective \par \tabitem Appropriate for large wound areas & \tabitem Need to occur in a surgical room \par \tabitem Anaesthetic needed as a painful procedure \par \tabitem Expensive \\ \hline
    \textbf{Sharp} & Removal of necrotic tissue just above the limit of healthy tissue using surgical tools like scalpel, scissors and/or forceps & \tabitem Selective and quick \par \tabitem No anaesthetic needed \par \tabitem Can be undertaken in conjunction with other therapies \par \tabitem Can be done as a bedside procedure & \tabitem Does not achieve total debridement \par \tabitem It is based on the ability of the clinicians to recognise different tissues \\ \hline
    \textbf{Enzymatic} & Use of exogenous proteolytic enzymes (e.g. collagenase, papain) to break down necrotic tissue & \tabitem Selective technique & \tabitem Slow process, but in conjunction with moisture-retentive dressings, it can increase debriding activity \\ \hline
    \textbf{Mechanical} & Can be achieved with different tools and/or equipment. Most common: wet-to-dry gauze dressings. It consists in applying wet gauze to the wound that dries, adhering to the top layer of the wound, pulling it off upon removal & \tabitem Wet-to-dry is not selective \par \tabitem Newer techniques are more selective, faster and relatively pain-free (e.g. monofilament pad) & \tabitem Can be very painful for the patient \par \tabitem High numbers of dressings needed can result in a rather expensive technique \par \tabitem Gauze can leave remnants in the wound that could lead to further inflammation \\ \hline
    \textbf{Autolytic} & Use of endogenous proteolytic enzymes to break down necrotic tissue. Requires moist wound environment (via moisture-controlling dressings) & \tabitem Can be used as a pre-debridement technique or for maintenance debridement  & \tabitem Slow process, and it could lead to potential infection and maceration \\ \hline
    \textbf{Biological} & Use of lab-grown larvae of green bottle fly.  They release an enzyme that breaks down both necrotic tissue and bioburden & \tabitem Highly selective and rapid \par \tabitem Larvae release ammonia, increasing wound pH and acting as a preventative measure for further biofilm growth & \tabitem Not suitable for all patients or wounds \par \tabitem Costs are higher than autolytic, but treatment time is shorter \\ \hline
    \textbf{Ultrasonic} & Devices deliver ultrasound directly onto the wound bed or via atomised solution & \tabitem Fast and selective \par \tabitem Devices present irrigation systems and different probes to be used on different wound types & \tabitem High cost \par \tabitem Long set up and clean up times \par \tabitem Not commonly available \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}
    }
\end{landscape}
```

The errors I get are:

```
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \penalty \@M \futurelet \@let@token \LT@@h...
l.198     \hline
                 \hline \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Mode of Action} & \textbf{Ad...
I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.

! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.198     \hline \hline
                        \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Mode of Action} & \textbf{Ad...
I expect to see \omit only after tab marks or the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
```

and

```
                        
l.198     \hline \hline
                        \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Mode of Action} & \textbf{Ad...
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
```

Which appear at the highlighted line.

This is what looks like in the compiled pdf which looks fine to me:
[image: table in compiled pdf]

Comment: do not show code snippets, always extend them to a small but complete document. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: if I guess a preamble, the first error   is `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`  the error you show is just tex trying to recover

Comment: `longtable` does not have  a `[ht]` argument,

Comment: the error is `\centering` which you can delete as it does nothing in that location

Comment: you have changed the example, you are now missing `\\ ` after `\label`

Answer (score 3):

If I guess an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
%\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
\begin{longtable}[ht]{M{2.5cm}M{7.20cm}M{7.25cm}M{7.5cm}}
    \caption{Type of debridement techniques. \textit{Adapted from Gray et al. (2011), Vowden (2011).}}
    \label{techn}
    \centering 
    \\ \hline 
    \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Mode of Action} &       \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Surgical} & Removal of necrotic and healthy tissue to achieve a healthy bleeding wound & \begin{itemize}
            \item Selective
            \item Appropriate for large wound areas
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Need to occur in a surgical room
            \item Anaesthetic needed as a painful procedure
            \item Expensive
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Sharp} & Removal of necrotic tissue just above the limit of healthy tissue using surgical tools like scalpel, scissors and/or forceps & \begin{itemize}
            \item Selective and quick
            \item No anaesthetic needed
            \item Can be undertaken in conjunction with other therapies
            \item Can be done as a bedside procedure
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Does not achieve total debridement
            \item It is based on the ability of the clinicians to recognise different tissues
        \end{itemize}\\ \hline
        \textbf{Enzymatic} & Use of exogenous proteolytic enzymes (e.g. collagenase, papain) to break down necrotic tissue & \begin{itemize}
            \item Selective technique
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Slow process, but in conjunction with moisture-retentive dressings, it can increase debriding activity
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Mechanical} & Can be achieved with different tools and/or equipment. Most common: wet-to-dry gauze dressings. It consists in applying wet gauze to the wound that dries, adhering to the top layer of the wound, pulling it off upon removal & \begin{itemize}
            \item Wet-to-dry is not selective
            \item Newer techniques are more selective, faster and relatively pain-free (e.g. monofilament pad)
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Can be very painful for the patient
            \item High numbers of dressings needed can result in a rather expensive technique
            \item Gauze can leave remnants in the wound that could lead to further inflammation
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Autolytic} & Use of endogenous proteolytic enzymes to break down necrotic tissue. Requires moist wound environment (via moisture-controlling dressings) & \begin{itemize}
            \item Can be used as a pre-debridement technique or for maintenance debridement
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Slow process, and it could lead to potential infection and maceration
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Biological} & Use of lab-grown larvae of green bottle fly.  They release an enzyme that breaks down both necrotic tissue and bioburden & \begin{itemize}
            \item Highly selective and rapid
            \item Larvae release ammonia, increasing wound pH and acting as a preventative measure for further biofilm growth
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Not suitable for all patients or wounds
            \item Costs are higher than autolytic, but treatment time is shorter
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Ultrasonic} & Devices deliver ultrasound directly onto the wound bed or via atomised solution & \begin{itemize}
            \item Fast and selective
            \item Devices present irrigation systems and different probes to be used on different wound types
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item High cost
            \item Long set up and clean up times
            \item Not commonly available 
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline 
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
%\endgroup

\end{document}
```

It produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.15     \\ \hline
                  
?
```

Only if you scroll past this error you see spurious errors from the internal definition of `\hline` (`\multispan`)

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \penalty \@M \futurelet \@let@token \LT@@h...
l.15     \\ \hline
                  
? 
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.16     \textbf
                {Type} & \textbf{Mode of Action} &       \textbf{Advantages}...

?
```

The original error is due to `\centering` which in that location just defines `\\`   to end a centred text line, not a table row, so you can delete, and all errors go:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
%\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
\begin{longtable}[ht]{M{2.5cm}M{7.20cm}M{7.25cm}M{7.5cm}}
    \caption{Type of debridement techniques. \textit{Adapted from Gray et al. (2011), Vowden (2011).}}
    \label{techn}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    \centering 
    \\ \hline 
    \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Mode of Action} &       \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Surgical} & Removal of necrotic and healthy tissue to achieve a healthy bleeding wound & \begin{itemize}
            \item Selective
            \item Appropriate for large wound areas
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Need to occur in a surgical room
            \item Anaesthetic needed as a painful procedure
            \item Expensive
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Sharp} & Removal of necrotic tissue just above the limit of healthy tissue using surgical tools like scalpel, scissors and/or forceps & \begin{itemize}
            \item Selective and quick
            \item No anaesthetic needed
            \item Can be undertaken in conjunction with other therapies
            \item Can be done as a bedside procedure
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Does not achieve total debridement
            \item It is based on the ability of the clinicians to recognise different tissues
        \end{itemize}\\ \hline
        \textbf{Enzymatic} & Use of exogenous proteolytic enzymes (e.g. collagenase, papain) to break down necrotic tissue & \begin{itemize}
            \item Selective technique
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Slow process, but in conjunction with moisture-retentive dressings, it can increase debriding activity
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Mechanical} & Can be achieved with different tools and/or equipment. Most common: wet-to-dry gauze dressings. It consists in applying wet gauze to the wound that dries, adhering to the top layer of the wound, pulling it off upon removal & \begin{itemize}
            \item Wet-to-dry is not selective
            \item Newer techniques are more selective, faster and relatively pain-free (e.g. monofilament pad)
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Can be very painful for the patient
            \item High numbers of dressings needed can result in a rather expensive technique
            \item Gauze can leave remnants in the wound that could lead to further inflammation
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Autolytic} & Use of endogenous proteolytic enzymes to break down necrotic tissue. Requires moist wound environment (via moisture-controlling dressings) & \begin{itemize}
            \item Can be used as a pre-debridement technique or for maintenance debridement
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Slow process, and it could lead to potential infection and maceration
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Biological} & Use of lab-grown larvae of green bottle fly.  They release an enzyme that breaks down both necrotic tissue and bioburden & \begin{itemize}
            \item Highly selective and rapid
            \item Larvae release ammonia, increasing wound pH and acting as a preventative measure for further biofilm growth
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Not suitable for all patients or wounds
            \item Costs are higher than autolytic, but treatment time is shorter
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Ultrasonic} & Devices deliver ultrasound directly onto the wound bed or via atomised solution & \begin{itemize}
            \item Fast and selective
            \item Devices present irrigation systems and different probes to be used on different wound types
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
            \item High cost
            \item Long set up and clean up times
            \item Not commonly available 
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline 
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
%\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @David thank you! It worked but I'm getting new errors now. I have updated the question.

Comment: @dvverdo better to ask a new question,  but the example you added can not work, it has no `\begin{document}`